# Move tables next to each other

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have 3 tables in my page, like this:

```
Table1
Table2
Table3
```

Now how can I move tables 2 and 3 to be next to table1 with table3 being below table2, something like this:

```
       Table2
Table1 Table3
```

HTML of the tables:

```
    <table id="table-1">
       <tbody>
         <tr class="row-1">
           <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-2">
           <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
        </tr>

    <table id="table-2">
       <tbody>
         <tr class="row-1">
           <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-2">
           <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
        </tr>

<table id="table-3">
       <tbody>
         <tr class="row-1">
           <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-2">
           <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can float them to the left and the right:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#table-1 { 
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}
#table-2 { 
  border: 2px solid blue;
  float: right;
}
#table-3 { 
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  float: right;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<table id="table-1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row-1">
      <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2">
      <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="table-2">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row-1">
      <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2">
      <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="table-3">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row-1">
      <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2">
      <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or as alternative, with two "column" divs:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#table-1 { border: 2px solid red; }
#table-2 { border: 2px solid blue; }
#table-3 { border: 2px solid yellow; }

#col1, #col2 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="col1">
  <table id="table-1">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row-1">
        <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-2">
        <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="col2">
  <table id="table-2">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row-1">
        <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-2">
        <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="table-3">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row-1">
        <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-2">
        <td class="column-1">something</td><td class="column-2">something</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help u....

Take three `divs` and put each `table` in each divs and then use css property of `float:left`

Answer (score 0):

```css
#table-1{float:left;}
```

```html
<table id="table-1">
<tbody>
<tr class="row-1">
    <td class="column-1">something1</td><td class="column-2">something1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-2">
    <td class="column-1">something1</td><td class="column-2">something1</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
<table id="table-2">
<tbody>
<tr class="row-1">
    <td class="column-1">something2</td><td class="column-2">something2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-2">
    <td class="column-1">something2</td><td class="column-2">something2</td>
</tr>

<table id="table-3">
<tbody>
<tr class="row-1">
    <td class="column-1">something3</td><td class="column-2">something3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-2">
    <td class="column-1">something3</td><td class="column-2">something3</td>
</tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```html
<div style="float:left">
     <table id="table-1">
         <tr><td>Table11</td><td>Table12</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Table13</td><td>Table14</td></tr>
     </table>
</div>

<div style="float:right">
     <table id="table-2">
         <tr><td>Table21</td><td>Table22</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Table23</td><td>Table24</td></tr>
     </table>

     <table id="table-3">
         <tr><td>Table31</td><td>Table32</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Table33</td><td>Table34</td></tr>
     </table>
  </div>
```